# Static class properties with Class<MyClass> myClass

Tags: java

I am experimenting here a bit.

Say I have a class :

```
static class MyClass {
    static String property = "myProperty";
}
```

and a method:

```
public static void myMethod0(Class<MyClass> clazz)  {
   try {
        MyClass myClass = clazz.newInstance();
        System.out.println (myClass.property);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

and to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    myMethod0(MyClass.class);
}
```

myMethod0 would work here, however, I am creating a new instance in order to reach the property. 
Since the properties are static I should be able to reach them without actually creating any instance. For example as you would do when reaching a static property, ie **MyClass.property**

To summarize: 
Is it possible to reach the static property of MyClass, by having Class clazz = MyClass.class ?

Thanks !

**

### EDIT:

**
To put the above in perspective and what I am actually trying to accomplish:

```
public static class PDF_1 { public static PDF_1 it = new PDF_1();
    static String contentType = "application/pdf";
    static String fileEnding = "pdf";
}
static void myMethod0(PDF_1 pdf) {
    System.out.println(pdf.fileEnding);
}


public enum PDF_2 {it;
    static String contentType = "application/pdf";
    static String fileEnding = "pdf";        
}
static void myMethod1(PDF_2 pdf) {
   System.out.println(pdf.fileEnding);
}  

public static void main(String[] args ) {
    myMethod0(PDF_1.it); // Works fine! However very verbose because of public static PDF_1 it = new PDF_1();
    myMethod1(PDF_2.it); // Works fine! Somewhat verbose though because of the "it" keyword        
}
```

The whole idea as to what I am trying to accomplish with this, is that too often do I see people declare lots of strings, ie:

```
static class Constants {
    static String PDF_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/pdf";
    static String PDF_FILE_ENDING = "pdf";

    static String HTML_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html";
    static String HTML_FILE_ENDING = "html";
}

// There is no way knowing what type the method actually wants. Is it contentType, fileEnding or something entirely different ? 
public void myMethod(String str) {

}
```

What I am trying to achieve is something that would allow you to pass a main class/enum, ie: PDF and the method will itself determine what it will use. The caller will just know what to pass, a PDF or HTML class/enum. I am also looking for something that is this refactor friendly as well. It is also of interest not to complicate the declaration of this creation. I find fully blown enums just as obtrusive as a class, and can be hard to read. The ide a is that I am just grouping the two strings in a parent object "PDF" and "HTML".  An enum:

```
public enum SomeType {
    PDF("application/pdf", "pdf"), HTML(...);
    String contentType;
    String fileEnding;        
    // Constructor ... 
}
```

Would not allow you to declare a method and specify that this method expects the HTML stuff. Only that the enum type is of type SomeType. There is a risk that "someone" would pass SomeType.PDF to that method. What I am doing with the enum and class seems like a noob solution, and the Java language should provide a feature like this, or does it already?

Does this make sense?

Comment: You shouldn't change posted questions like that. The whole edit is a new question, and should be posted as one. Feel free to link to the new question in this one.

Comment: yeah, i know.. but I couldn't delete this one and post a new one. People will often complain about asking the same question several times, so I didnt want to repost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public enum PDF { it;
    static String contentType = "application/pdf";
    static String fileEnding = "pdf";        
}
static void myMethod1(PDF pdf) {
   System.out.println(pdf.fileEnding);
}  

public static void main(String[] args ) {
    myMethod1(PDF.it); // Works fine! Somewhat verbose though because of the "it" keyword. Not 100% ideal!      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection

```
System.out.println(myClass.getDeclaredField("property").get(null));
```

The `get`-method usually requires an instance to get the attribute from, but since `property` is static, you may pass it a `null`.

Comment: Thanks, this was a new approach to me. However, it is not solid from a refactoring perspective as it is using a string to access the property.

Comment: I completely agree with you. reflection is a last resort. To the extent of my knowledge this is however not possible without reflection :/

Answer (score 0):

I hope you meant this - I wrote tests with hamcrest - so don't wonder ;)

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import org.junit.Test;


public class TestEnumEnding {



    @Test
    public void whenMethod1WithFiletypeHtmlWeShouldGetStringText_Html() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        String contentType = null;
        // Act
        contentType = method1(Filetype.HTML);
        // Assert
        assertThat(contentType, is("text/html"));

    }

    @Test
    public void whenMethod1WithFiletypePdfWeShouldGetapplication_pdf() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        String contentType = null;
        // Act
        contentType = method1(Filetype.PDF);
        // Assert
        assertThat(contentType, is("application/pdf"));

    }

    private static String method1 (Filetype anyFiletype) {
        return anyFiletype.getContentType();

    }

    public enum Filetype {

        HTML("html","text/html"), PDF("pdf","application/pdf");

        private final String fileEnding;
        private final String contentType;

        private Filetype(String fileEnding, String contentType) {
            this.fileEnding = fileEnding;
            this.contentType = contentType;
        }

        public String getFileEnding() {
            return this.fileEnding;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            return this.contentType;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this would the obtrusive part of it. It is also not clear as to what type we want to pass in to this method, HTML values or PDF values. One will create a PDF the other will not. Going from declaring static fields ( wish is the lazy programmers way ) to fully blown enum (~class more or less ). Enums are hard to read, they are just like a class. I think I would find my solution with the enum above a bit more "light". I will post it as an answer.

Comment: enums are for lazy programmers, you specify them just once and use them through your whole program without breaking your head if there will be more values or not. you just take care of your classes to get the values they need (like fileending, charset or whatever is needed). I don't know which of your enums you prefer, but if you want to do it with 2 values, you should have the enum like mine. You can put enum into a new file and import it in the classes where you need it...